# Where is the kernel symbol __tracepoint_module_load defined?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, trace, tracepoint

Where is the kernel symbol `__tracepoint_module_load` defined?
I saw it once in `/proc/kallsyms`, but now I can't find it.

[bootlin.com/linux/](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.2/source/kernel/tracepoint.c) cannot find it, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where is the kernel symbol __tracepoint_module_load defined ?

There is [`TRACE_EVENT`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.2/source/include/linux/tracepoint.h#L531) macro, which eventually uses [`__DECLARE_TRACE`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.2/source/include/linux/tracepoint.h#L231), where you can see:

```
extern struct tracepoint __tracepoint_##name;
```

So we can find the appropriate `TRACE_EVENT` "call" for `module_load` in [include/trace/events/module.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.2/source/include/trace/events/module.h#L31):

```
TRACE_EVENT(module_load,
...
```

In *`/proc/kallsyms`* output *`D`* means that the symbol is in the initialized data section:

```
ffffffff91af5240 D __tracepoint_module_load
```

---

P.S. In case of preprocessor magic *elixir.bootlin.com* is not so useful. To make a real investigation just clone [Linux kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux) or download the appropriate sources from [pub](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/).

Comment: OK thanks. That was difficult. Also, do you know what options the Kernel needs to be built with, in order for the `__tracepoint_module_load` symbol to become exported to `/proc/kallsyms` ? I noticed that `CONFIG_MODULES` is needed...but what else ? Are `CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL` and `CONFIG_TRACEPOINTS` needed, too ?